# Android internet permissions for second activity

Tags: android, permissions

I have been trying to download some stuff from the internet in my app, but in the second activity. I have added the permission request, and it works in my first activity, but not in the second one? is there anything i'm forgetting? otherwise, why would i possibly be getting a permission error?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.example.ruslan.seriesstuff">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Main2Activity">
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: can you post your code here?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], including the Java stack trace associated with your error, the code that is triggering the crash, and your manifest.

Comment: post your logcat output here

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurred because of the newer version of android, in my case 6.0. I solved this problem by doing the following. Long press on the app icon in your phone, drag it to the appeared icon of app info. There go to the permissions of the app and make sure you have actually provided the permission to the internet. That's it!